# Building a multi step form - bad practice to use 0 height element?

Tags: angular

I have a requirement to build a multi step form which includes one of the components to persist on the page from the start with a height of 0. The reason is that if the element is removed from the DOM, we lose connection to it and the service it provides which will break the entire app.

So we end up having to show/hide components from each step of the flow while always having that one component either shown or with a height of 0.

Is this ok from a best practice standpoint? or is 0 height frowned upon and I should be doing something more like an accordion for each component where they always display on the one page (without the 0 height requirement)?

Comment: sounds like you need to redesign you app. You app shouldn't be relaying on a on dom element to have the connection. 1) should show some code or have a stackbliz 2) I wouldn't use routes for a multi step, I would use conditionals or even better use the steppers from Angular material or PrimeNG..and answering your question, yes it is bad practice

Comment: Thank you, @PatricioVargas it feels like bad practice but I cannot find any documentation out there stating this. Is there anything you could point me to? I'm afraid that if I don't have some solid proof, my team will end up going this route of using 0 height and we'll end up paying for it down the road.

Comment: Why is it a component and not a service?

Comment: @brainmonger if you can show some code we can point you at a better direction

Comment: It is a component built by another team which we are relying on to process payments. It was build such that it is not a service, but a component which has to always be in the dom in order to function.

Comment: @PatricioVargas Unfortunately I cannot show much code because this is in the beginning stages.. but basically they want to do this: step 1) guest info step 2) payment step 3) verify and can edit either inline on the verify or be taken back to the previous steps.. but in each case that payment component has to always remain in the dom (even if just 0 height). I would think a single page model using an accordion would be a better way to work with this restriction. Thoughts?

Comment: Why is 0 height component a bad practice? I've been having a tough time explaining exactly why other than it's hacky and not a clean approach.

Comment: If you control the component and can refactor it, then surely you need to rethink the design. However, am not convinced that having a 0 height component is bad practice. Esp. since there are a lot of analytics or tracking libs which use 0 or 1 px height components injected on client pages. There also the requirement is very much similar to your third party component i.e. they need to be loaded (present in dom) to do their work.

Comment: Need working example/code snippet for more clarification. Thanks